# NoReverseMatch at /ProjektAJ/songs/ Reverse for 'songs' with arguments '('all',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['ProjektAJ\\/songs/$']

Tags: python, django

I would like to return list of all songs in my project from my local sqlite

**HTML file**

```
<li class="{% block songs_active %}{% endblock %}">
    <a href="{% url 'ProjektAJ:songs' %}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp; Songs
    </a>
</li>
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^songs/$', views.SongsView.as_view(), name='songs'),
```

**views.py**

```
class SongsView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'ProjektAJ/songs.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_songs'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Song.objects.all()
```

**models.py**

```
class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('ProjektAJ:index')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_title
```

I have error like below

```
NoReverseMatch at /ProjektAJ/songs/
Reverse for 'songs' with arguments '('all',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['ProjektAJ\\/songs/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/ProjektAJ/songs/
Django Version: 2.0.6
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'songs' with arguments '('all',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['ProjektAJ\\/songs/$']
Exception Location: G:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 636
Python Executable:  G:\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Adrian Skibiński\\ProbaDjango\\django_projekt',
 'G:\\Python\\Python36-32\\python36.zip',
 'G:\\Python\\Python36-32\\DLLs',
 'G:\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib',
 'G:\\Python\\Python36-32',
 'G:\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 8 Sep 2018 16:29:51 +0000
```

Could you tell me what I do wrong in this case?

Comment: Thiis error occurs on which page exactly? Are you sure you are showing (enough of) the correct template?

Comment: This error appear when I want click button "Songs" on my main page. At this moment ProjektAJ/songs.html contains only one string "TEST" rest of logic is comment

Comment: The html snippet is the link that you click when you see the error, I assume?

Comment: This code is not caused by any of the code you have posted here. Somewhere you are doing either `reverse('songs', ('all',))` in Python, or `{% url 'songs' 'all' %}` in a template. That is the code you need to post.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is minimal code provided to understand the question better, the url `r'^songs/$'` does not point to the folder `ProjektAJ` where the template is. Maybe if you posted the general structure of the project/app it would be easier to assist.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your time and your willing to resolve my problem.
I found the solution.

**HTML file**

```
<li class="{% block songs_active %}{% endblock %}">
   <a href="{% url 'ProjektAJ:songs' 'all' %}">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp; Songs
   </a>
</li>
```

I had to add `{% url 'ProjektAJ:songs' 'all' %}` to my HTML template, and next I modified the url to     `url(r'^songs/(?P<filter_by>[a-zA_Z]+)/$', views.SongsView.as_view(), name='songs'),`

Now it works correctly.
Thanks for your time and I hope this topic will be useful for other with similar trouble.